# Address not displaying in opengts

Tags: reverse-geocoding, opengts

I am using Opengts to track some devices. I am getting their coordinates but I am unable to see the address on opengts web. While writing this command on command line I am getting the address :

```
rgTest pl:default gp:39.12345/-142.12345
```

I have changed the setting in private.xml. If anyone know about this issue, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Cross check if you have followed these steps.

1) Make reverse-geocode provider true in private.xml(try using google v3,**active="${Domain.ReverseGeocodeProvider.active=true}"** )

2) Check in tomcat logs for catalina.out wich says if the reverse-geocoding is being sent to google in this case.

3) Checking in config.conf file **startupInit.EventData.AddressFieldInfo=true**
(Remove '#')

Comment: so after following the steps, are you supposed to also restart apache tomcat? And also recompile the openGTS code with ant?

Comment: After applying these changes I had to rebuild track, events and gprmc for OpenGTS to start showing addresses.